# Why does `add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-form' )` disable client side validation?

Tags: comment-form, html5, add-theme-support

In order to use HTML5 markup for the comment forms, I add the following code snippet to `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-form' ) );
```

However, it disables client side validation on form submit and I get redirected to an error page:

[image: Error page redirect]

Now, if I remove `add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-form' ) );` and submit the comment form, I get client side validation:

[image: Client side validation]

Can anybody explain why this is? Is it a bug? Or expected behavior?

I am currently using WordPress 4.7.

Comment: Could be a bug with your current theme/plugin? Do you get the same behavior for any of the default themes, e.g. TwentySixteen, that supports html5 comment-form?

Comment: The default theme for my WordPress is TwentySeventeen and looking at the `functions.php` for that theme shows it is also enabling html5 markup for `comment-form`. When I use that default theme, I don't get client-side validation and it just redirects to the error page. But when I comment out `comment-form` from default theme's `functions.php`, client-side validation works. I don't think its a bug with my current theme, but some other issue. I'm just commenting out `comment-form` for now so I get client validation. I just think its odd.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a bug. This is how core handles it. If you look into `/wp-includes/comment-template.php`, you'll notice, that the only difference in `<form>` element, is `novalidate` attribute added, when `current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'comment-form' )` is true. But there are other html elements within comment form, which are affected by theme's choice of html5 support. For example:
input field for email ( `type="email"` - html5, `type="text"` - xhtml ), and input field for url ( `type="url"` - html5, `type="text"` - xhtml ).

I would not recommend to remove theme support for html5. WordPress, now, builds our documents with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which means, HTML5. If we do remove support, our document will not validate as correct XTML5.

So, how to deal with this offending `novalidate` attribute? Simple jQuery script will fix it.

Create file `removenovalidate.js` and put the code below in it:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('#commentform').removeAttr('novalidate');
});
```

Save this file to your theme's folder. Add the code below to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function fpw_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( is_single() ) { 
        wp_register_script( 'fpw_remove_novalidate', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/removenovalidate.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fpw_remove_novalidate' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fpw_enqueue_scripts', 10 );
```

All done. Your comments form will validate now.

Comment: I agree with you. Omitting `'comment-form'` from theme support adds the problematic `novalidate` attribute to `<form>` as well as adding proper html5 input types for email and url (i.e., `type="email" and type="url"`). Otherwise, adding `add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-form' ) );` removes the offending `novalidate` attribute, but also sets `type=text` for email and url inputs. You're solution of enabling theme support for `'comment-form'` works, but you're using jQuery to manipulate the DOM and remove the `novalidate` attribute from the comment form.

Comment: Basically, if you want client side validation for wp comment forms, the `<form>` element cannot have `novalidate` attribute. You have 2 choices. 1) Omit/comment-out `comment-form` from `add-theme-support`. This will work, but the downside is that email and url inputs will be `type=text` (which is xhtml instead of html5). 2) Add/enable `comment-form` from `add-theme-support`, but also use jQuery to remove `novalidate` attribute from comment form. This will also work, but the downside is that you have to additionally use javascript to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Check more in depth analysis of the problem [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265329/html5-theme-support-for-comments-form-novalidate-how-to-handle-it-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `novalidate` attribute with this simple Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var commentForm = document.getElementById('commentform'); 
    commentForm.removeAttribute('novalidate');
</script>
```

No jQuery needed.

You can include the following code to run script just on posts:

#### footer.php

```
<?php if( is_singular() ) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var commentForm = document.getElementById('commentform');
        commentForm.removeAttribute('novalidate');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```